# Code first Generating Extra Columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I have a set of players that are linked together through a `FriendLinker` table.

The table links two players together (in this case, its player->friend). I have the player setup in the following way:

```
public class Player
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key, Column(Order=0)]
    public Guid PlayerId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FriendLinker> Friends { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; } //Will be switched to byte[] for hash

    [MaxLength(100)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

and the linker table is setup like this:

```
public class FriendLinker
{
    [Key]
    public int FriendLinkerId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Player Player { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Player Friend { get; set; }
}
```

However, this is generating the following migration:

```
CreateTable(
"dbo.FriendLinkers",
c => new
{
     FriendLinkerId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
     Player_PlayerId = c.Guid(),
     Friend_PlayerId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
     Player_PlayerId1 = c.Guid(nullable: false),
})
.PrimaryKey(t => t.FriendLinkerId)
.ForeignKey("dbo.Players", t => t.Player_PlayerId)
.ForeignKey("dbo.Players", t => t.Friend_PlayerId, cascadeDelete: false)
.ForeignKey("dbo.Players", t => t.Player_PlayerId1, cascadeDelete: false)
.Index(t => t.Player_PlayerId)
.Index(t => t.Friend_PlayerId)
.Index(t => t.Player_PlayerId1);
```

The result creates an extra column `Player_PlayerId1`. When I do `player.Friends.add(..)`, the playerId is inserted into PlayerId1.

What should I do to prevent that extra column `PlayerId1` being generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens, because `FriendLinker` class has two links to `Player` class, but `Player` class has only one link and EF little confused about it, as a result additional column `Player_PlayerId1` appears, this column is exactly linked to `Player`(`ICollection` property, that is why: *When I do player.Friends.add(..), the playerId is inserted into PlayerId1.*). Two other columns, that you specified, considered as implicitly linked to `Player` class. You can fix it by adding second link to `FriendLinker` class at `Player` class declaration and specify to which concrete properties this links will be related by means of `InverseProperty` attribute's constructor parameter:

```
public class Player
{
    [InverseProperty("Player")]
    public virtual ICollection<FriendLinker> Players { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Friend")]
    public virtual ICollection<FriendLinker> Friends { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; } //Will be switched to byte[] for hash

    [MaxLength(100)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```